# Laravel filtered collection is no longer filtered after json encoding

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

I have an Eloquent collection with an eager loaded relationship. When I filter this eager loaded relationship, it works fine, but if I encode it as JSON (to pass it to my front end Javascript framework), the collection is no longer filtered.

Simplified example:

```
$questions = Question::with('variables')->get();

foreach($questions as $key => $q) {
  $questions[$key]->variables = $q->variables->reject(function($v) {
    return $v->type == 3;
  });
}

dd($questions);
```

If I look at the $questions variable at this point, my collection is correctly filtered.  If, however, I add `json_decode(json_encode($questions))` following line before dumping, the collection is no longer filtered.

Note that in my real application, I have to do some things with the rejected variables before throwing them out of the collection, so I cannot simply filter them out during the query.

My workaround right now is to json encode and decode the collection, then do an array filter to get rid of the variables I do not want to pass to the front end.  This works, but seems like a terribly inelegant and unnecessary solution.  Am I doing something wrong or is this the expected behavior?

I'm still running Laravel 5.8 on this application in the event that this behavior has changed on newer versions.

Comment: In your code, `$questions` is a single model, not a collection.

Comment: That was an error; I meant to write get(), which I have now edited.. The crux of the question is filtering the nested collection, which cannot be done at the time of query because those variables need to be used for other reasons before filtering them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```php
$questionsWithFilteredVariables = $questions->map(function($question) {
    $variables = $question->variables->reject(fn($var) => $var->type === 3);

    unset($question->variables);
    $question->variables = $variables;

    return $question;
});

//Now do json_decode(json_encode(...)), it will still contain filtered variables

$questionsWithFilteredVariables = json_decode(
    json_encode($questionsWithFilteredVariables)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just load the variables twice then?

```php
$questions = Question::with(['variables' => fn($v) => $v->where('type', '!=', 3)])->get();
// do whatever you need to do with the filtered collection

// reload variables relationship
$questions->load('variables');
// do whatever you need to do with the question and all its variables.
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I made an error in my initial question; I should have listed get() instead of find() on the query.  As I mentioned in my question, I cannot filter during the query because I need to do some computations using the variables with type 3 before returning the collection without them (this is not shown in the simplified example).

Comment: What about loading the variables twice? You could even just make them different variables

Comment: the @IGP answer is correct.
but maybe need a little change since we need to filter `type = 3` to `$v->where('type', '!=', 3)`